# Get custom columns from folder into document library C#

Tags: csom, provider-hosted-app

I'm doing a provider-hosted app and I'm trying to get custom column I've created in a content type that inherits from folder(parent) I get the folder like so:

```
 Folder folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(pathForfolder);
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can i get all the fields for a folder?

> e.g var name = folder["field"]

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Folder.ListItemAllFields` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx) to retrieve folder associated list item properties

**Example**

```
Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
ctx.Load(folder,f => f.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(folder.ListItemAllFields["Title"]);
```